# Debugging Encrypted Malware with Multiple Threads

Tags: debugging, ollydbg, malware, winapi, thread

What is the best approach when debugging a multithreaded program that is yet to be encrypted? Where is the best place to put Breakpoints using Ollydbg?

Comment: It depends what you want to do, if you want to catch the decryption procedure - well, the best idea is probably to set the memory/hardware breakpoint on the encrypted data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the program is using standard cryptography libraries then hooking the exported functions of that library might be a good starting point